# Question about inequation in probability

Tags: probability, inequality

Given is an inequation in probability, where $X_n$ is a random variable and $X_n \to X$ in probability: $$\begin{align*} &P\{|X_n|\ge M, |X| < \frac{M}2\}+P\{|X_n|\ge M, |X|\ge \frac{M}2\}\\ &\quad \le P\{|X_n-X|\ge \frac{M}2\}+P\{|X|\ge\frac{M}2\} \end{align*}$$

I can see that in the first bracket on the left of the inequation, when you abstract $X_n$ by $X$, you get the first bracket on the right of the inequation, but the rest seems like a enigma.

Answer (score 0):

$|X_n| \geq M$ and $|X|< M/2$ implies, by the triangle inequality

$$|X_n-X| \geq |X_n|-|X| \geq M- \frac{M}{2} = \frac{M}{2},$$

i.e.

$$\left\{|X_n| \geq M, |X| < \frac{M}{2} \right\} \subseteq \left\{|X_n-X| \geq \frac{M}{2} \right\}.$$

Consequently,

$$\mathbb{P}\left(|X_n| \geq M, |X| < \frac{M}{2} \right) \leq \mathbb{P}\left(|X_n-X| \geq \frac{M}{2} \right).$$

Moreover,

$$\left\{|X_n| \geq M, |X| \geq \frac{M}{2} \right\} \subseteq \left\{|X| \geq \frac{M}{2}\right\},$$

and therefore

$$\mathbb{P}\left(|X_n| \geq M, |X| \geq \frac{M}{2} \right) \leq \mathbb{P}\left(|X| \geq \frac{M}{2} \right).$$

Combining both inequalities, finishes the proof.